# Is there any MathML Renderer Component for .Net App?

Tags: c#, .net, mathml

Is there any component of MathML Renderer which can be used by Dot Net App? I hope you could help me find one no matter how much it costs.

Detailed Requirements:

1. it can provides a control for equation edit
2. it must not be a COM component
3. it must support Content MathML markup (it will be better if it could support both Content and Presentation markup)
4. it could generate the markup according to the formula
5. it could generate the formula according to the markup

I have found some tools such as MathML .Net Control and NuGenEQML .Net, but unluckily, both  two components don't support Content Markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same need.  There's only three options that I am aware of:

= MathFlow by Decision Science - I will soon be evaluating this one and am hopeful it will be my new solution; they've provided presentation MathML for MS Word for a long time; they finally came out with a Content MathML offering

= Integre - I've used their COM control in .NET... painful; they have a Java one, but was never able to get them to do a .NET wrapper; they are working on a Flash one that I thought I'd be able to wrap and embed, but I've grown tired of waiting

= Forumulator by Hermitech - seems to be a step down from the two above

If you uncover any others, please post here.